# Unable to access Rails app on NGinx and Thin without port in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin

So I deployed my Rail 3 app with a pretty standard NGinx and Thin configurations. But I am stuck with three problems -

- that I can access the app only by appending the port to the URL (domain.com:port)
- that www.domain.com still shows the NGinx welcome screen and
- that accessing the app using port in URL should ideally not work

My NGinx conf:

```
upstream thin_cluster {
    <ip_address>:3000;
    <ip_address>:3001;
    <ip_address>:3002;
}

server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;

        root /home/deployer/apps/appname/current/public;

        location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @thin;
        }   

        location @thin {
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://thin_cluster;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504 /500.html;

        client_max_body_size 50M;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

My Thin conf:

```
---
chdir: /home/deployer/apps/appname/current
environment: production
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 3000
timeout: 30
log: log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 100
require: []
wait: 30
servers: 3
daemonize: true
onebyone: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, answering my question for the umpteenth time. And this one is a pretty foolish mistake, perhaps due to lack of sleep.

The problem is right here

`upstream thin_cluster {
    <ip_address>:3000;
    <ip_address>:3001;
    <ip_address>:3002;
}`

It should contain the localhost address on which Thin is running. So this would be:

`upstream thin_cluster {
    127.0.0.1:3000;
    127.0.0.1:3001;
    127.0.0.1:3002;
}`

However I can still access the app by appending the port number to it. Ideally this should redirect to the proper URL. Perhaps `proxy_redirect` can help?

Comment: You need to firewall your local port or use socket connection scheme.